# Can we solve the following ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I would like to understand the solution to the following Ode, can we solve that? This there any idea that we can analysis something on that?

$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u(x)+\sinh(u)=0$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u'u''+u'\sinh u=0$$
integrates as
$$u'^2+2\cosh u=c.$$

Then

$$\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{c-2\cosh u}}=x+c'.$$

This integral can be solved by the change of variable $t=e^u$, leading to the inverse of a quadratic polynomial, the antiderivative of which is an arc tangent or an argument of hyperbolic tangent.

---

**Update:**

The square root was missing. This makes the integral non elementary.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot.

Comment: You forgot a square root in the integral. The integral shouldn't be elementary, considering that the ODE is almost (just change sinh to sin) the pendulum equation, which is solved in terms of elliptic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your equation in the form
$$\frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}=-\sinh(u(x))$$ then we multiply by $$\frac{du(x)}{dx}$$ and integrate
$$\int\frac{du(x)}{dx}\cdot \frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2}dx=\int-\frac{du(x)}{dx}\sinh(u(x))dx$$
This is $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{du(x)}{dx}\right)^2=-\cosh(u(x))+C$$
I hope you can finish now.

Comment: Thank you very much!